# Are the sources in QFT just particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral

I'm reading A. Zee's Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell, where he introduces QFT using path integral formulation.

One thing that I'm not sure I got correctly is this:

Zee adds a source term to the Klein Gordon Lagrangian:

$$\mathcal{L}=\phi(\partial^2 + m^2)\phi + J(x)\phi$$

and $J(x) \equiv J_1(x) + J_2(x) $.

What I understood is that these 2 sources are interpreted as particles. Is that correct?

The next thing is that he proceeds to do some calculations which I couldn't follow up with. Nevertheless, what I think was derived is that the field $\phi$ propagated from source $J_1(x)$ to source $J_2(x)$. And we can interpret this propagation as a force because we can see there is energy. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really particles. The source terms $J$ are a computational tool. First, they allow you to take the functional Fourier transform of the path phase factor $\exp(i S[\phi] / \hbar)$. Why is this useful? Because the quantities we're interested in when doing perturbation theory are the moments of this phase factor. Moments in real space are derivatives at the origin in the Fourier dual space, so the generating functional, $Z[J]$, is usually easier to compute the $N$-point functions from. Those are the quantities we need to construct the $S$-matrix, and other useful quantities.

Second, you can think of them as an imaginary non-conserved current that the field interacts with. We then use that current that we use to create and annihilate particles in the model and monitor their interactions. It is most close to the second sense that Zee is using $J$ - he looks at how the field produces a potential energy interaction between these imaginary external currents.

Comment: I read Peskin about J (pages 289-292) and yes, he introduces J as a mathematical tool - than a 'source'